# variadic macro doesn't compile

Tags: c, preprocessor, variadic-macros

I have 2 variadic macros, one of them compiles fine and the other one doesn't:

```
    #define ASSERT(x, ...)           assert_log(x, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
    #define TRACE (x, ...)           trace(x, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
...

libs/defs.h:16:71: error: __VA_ARGS__ can only appear in the expansion of a C99 variadic macro [-Werror]
   16 |         #define TRACE (x, ...)           trace(x, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
      |                                                                       ^
```

Their declared signatures:

```
void assert_log(int, const char*, int, const char* , ...);
void trace(int, const char*, int, const char* , ...);
```

Compilation flags:

```
CFLAGS= \
    -Wextra \
    -Werror \
    -Wall \
    -Wfloat-equal \
    -Wundef \
    -Wshadow \
    -Wcast-align \
    -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wswitch-enum \
    -Wformat=2 \
    -Werror=pointer-arith \
    -Wuninitialized \
    -pedantic \
    -std=c17 \
    -DDEBUG=1 \
    -g \
    -Og
```

Given the fact that their signature is the same, I don't understand why is GCC complaning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use Visual Studio 2022 C/C++, but I looked into your code.
Please try:

```
#define ASSERT(x, ...)    assert_log(x, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
#define TRACE(x, ...)     trace(x, __FILE__, __LINE__, __VA_ARGS__)
```

Hope you see the difference. Its a small one. You added a space after `TRACE` and before the `(` and that caused the error.

Comment: Oh lord. That's it. Accepting this answer in 7 minutes! Thank u